# riscv-tools build on power/ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, riscv

I'm going through the steps to build the Rocket Emulator and running into a problem. When building riscv-tools, jimtcl appears to not be happy with my machine type. I'm running on a POWER8 box with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on it.

I have been able to build using Ubuntu 17.04 under VirtBox on an X86 laptop and run through the ASM tests.

Error msgs below. Any help or hints/workarounds appreciated...

thanks

=========================================================

Starting RISC-V Toolchain build process

Removing existing riscv-openocd/build directory
Configuring project riscv-openocd
Error: /gpfs/ess1fs0/grassi/rocket-chip/riscv-tools/riscv-openocd/jimtcl/autosetup/config.guess: unable to guess system type

This script, last modified 2010-09-24, has failed to recognize the operating system you are using. It is advised that you download the most up to date version of the config scripts from

```
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;  f=config.guess;hb=HEAD
and
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD

If the version you run (/gpfs/ess1fs0/grassi/rocket-chip/riscv-tools/riscv-openocd/jimtcl/autosetup/config.guess) is already up to date, please send the following data and any information you think might be
```

pertinent to  in order to provide the needed
information to handle your system.

```
config.guess timestamp = 2010-09-24

uname -m = ppc64le
uname -r = 4.4.0-21-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:30:22 UTC 2016

/usr/bin/uname -p =
/bin/uname -X     =

hostinfo               =
/bin/universe          =
/usr/bin/arch -k       =
/bin/arch              =
/usr/bin/oslevel       =
/usr/convex/getsysinfo =

UNAME_MACHINE = ppc64le
UNAME_RELEASE = 4.4.0-21-generic
UNAME_SYSTEM  = Linux
UNAME_VERSION = #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:30:22 UTC 2016
child process exited abnormally
configure: error: ../../jimtcl/configure.gnu failed for jimtcl
```